# Why does mongomapper hit the database twice on query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, mongomapper

I have a simple query:

```
Store.where( params[:conditions] || {}).all
```

In logs ,it appears that mongo
mapper is firing the same query twice.

```
2013-07-28 14:01:05 - [DEBUG]:  MONGODB (0.7ms) db-development['stores'].find().
2013-07-28 14:01:05 - [DEBUG]:  MONGODB (0.5ms) db-development['stores'].find().
```

This seems like a bug to me. See also https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/pull/467.

Apparently, this bug still not fixed..

Does Anybody know how can I write the query with a single access to database?

**UPDATE:**

At `gem list`:

```
mongo_mapper (0.12.0)
plucky (0.5.2)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What versions of the mongomapper and plucky gems are you using? There was a bug causing this behavior once upon a time, but it's been fixed for a while now. Perhaps the `0.13.0.beta1` gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with Plucky 0.5.2. Try upgrading to MM 0.13.0.beta1, or using MM's master.

Comment: Thanks. It works better. But still I can see some queries that firing the same query twice.(not all of them).

Comment: If you can produce a unit test that demonstrates the behavior, please file a bug report on the project; I'm one of the maintainers and can track it down and fix it with a proper unit test.